# Kibana 4 index patterns time-field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

Is there a way to make Kibana-4 show a timestamp field which is a epoch time as the time-field when creating an index pattern.

I know how to make this with the _timestamp field by editing the metaFields in the settings, but I would like this to be a custom field.

Eg: Let's say this is the document I am storing in ES:

```
        {
            "_id": "AVCbqgiV7A6BIPyJuJRS",
            "_index": "scm-get-config-stg",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "serverDetails": {
                    "cloudDC": "xxx",
                    "cloudName": "yyyy",
                    "hostName": "hostname",
                    "ipAddress": "10.247.194.49",
                    "runOnEnv": "stg",
                    "serverTimestamp": 1445720623246
                }
            },
            "_type": "telemetry"
        }
```

Now I would like to create an index pattern where the Time-field name should be serverTimestamp.